# mysql use schema from local db project to create db structure upon new db creation in php

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have been working on a project on my localhost and I am wanting to use the database structure  that my local app is using on my live site. I have done a mysql dump and tried adding it to my pdo db creation script(on live site) but when the db is created their is no structure. Im not sure what im doing wrong and am having trouble finding any examples of it. Im not quite sure what im missing any pointers would be great. Thanks in advance

code ex.

```
$host="localhost"; 
$root="root"; 
$root_password="root"; 
$user='newuser';

$pass='newpass';
$db= 'companyid' . $companyid; 
    try {
        $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$host", $root, $root_password);

        $dbh->exec("CREATE DATABASE `$db`;
                CREATE USER '$user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '$pass';
                GRANT ALL ON `$db`.* TO '$user'@'localhost';
                FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
                CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `address` (
  `address` varchar(50) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_general_ci;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `checkpics`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `checkpics` (
  `image` varchar(120) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `amount` decimal(10,0) NOT NULL,
  `date` date NOT NULL,
  `photosmall` varchar(64) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `photobig` longblob NOT NULL,
  `timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `customerid` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `checknumber` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `checkamount` varchar(10) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `datepaid` varchar(10) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_general_ci;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `CityStateZip`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `CityStateZip` (
  `city` varchar(30) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `state` varchar(2) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `zip` varchar(10) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_general_ci;") 
        or die(print_r($dbh->errorInfo(), true));

    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        die("DB ERROR: ". $e->getMessage());
    }
```

Comment: @Fred-ii- the db name is defined `$db= 'companyid' . $companyid;` and pulled in at `$dbh->exec("CREATE DATABASE `$db`` the $companyid is pulled out through the $_session. I didnt want to paste in the whole code base sorry about that. The db creates fine but has no structure in it?? not sure why

Comment: I only noticed it after, which is why I deleted my comment. Try adding `$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` right after the connection is opened, see if it reveals anything.

Comment: @Fred-ii- do you want me to add this snippet below this code `$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$host", $root, $root_password);` ?

Comment: Yes, that's the place to put it under. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything else too. It could be a mix of both.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I ran the code and no error popped up. I think my syntax is wrong for the create table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I figured out the problem. When creating multiple tables you must run separate commands or use a mysqli multi query command and separate each instance via a ;